# Incremental MapReduce in Hadoop (with mongodb-hadoop adapter)

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to do a mapreduce work in Hadoop, that take and save results in MongoDB thanks mongo-hadoop connector.
There is a way to do in hadoop an incremental mapreduce like in MongoDB?

> *If documents exists for a given key in the result set and in the old collection, then a reduce operation (using the specified reduce function) will be performed on the two values and the result will be written to the output collection.*

Don't tell me to use MongoDB's MapReduce because its performances are embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't presently support this kind of incremental job in Mongo-Hadoop.  It may be supported in a future release.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected. Do you know _approximately_ when?